# Table without AI (Auto_Increment) PK? Use text PK instead

Tags: mysql, database

Currently im developing app for analysis of laboratory samples. This samples would have a code formed by 6 digits: correlative number + client code. For example `001231`, `002231`, `003231`, `001123`, `002123`...

So im in doubt about using this code as PK or use a common AI Integer as PK. Also, I suppose this code must be text, right? Because I can't store numbers as integer starting with 0...

Or would be better to keep an AI PK besides this 6 digits code?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it would have to be text to retain leading zeroes.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks. And about having an AI PK or use 6 digits code as PK, what would you recommend?

Comment: What is an `AI PK`?

Comment: AI = auto_increment?

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes, Auto_increment

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Auto_increment primary key. Thanks

Comment: @JamesR. You can't have a text AI PK.  But you can generate a 6 width number from the PK easily enough.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I know. But the question is about having AI PK + 6 digit mentioned code appart or directly use that 6 digit code as Primary Key (but not Auto Incremental) and not use autoincrement primary key on the table.

Comment: Um...integers don't have leading zeroes, period.  Leading zeroes are not significant and are not really there.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend just using a normal integer auto increment primary key, and then generating the text output you want:

```
SELECT
    id,
    LPAD(CAST(id AS CHAR(6)), 6, '0') AS id_padded
FROM yourTable;
```